# CMS Magento и 10 000 000 товаров?

Tags: cms, magento

CMS Magento и 10 000 000 товаров. Потянет ли ? Не велика ли для нее нагрузка ? Стоит ли вообще затевать магазин на ней ?

Comment: реально 10 лямов? не очепятка? Вы случано не Ali  парсить собрались?

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте вопрос по другому - а какой ещё фреймфорк (magento2 это уже даже не фреймвок а несколько независимых фрейморков) способен на такое.

Но с таким количеством товаров задача выходит далеко за рамки работы обычного e-commerce. Одним-двумя разрабами да дешманским vps, как, например при использовании **opencart**, тут не обойдётся.

ИМХО - для высоко нагруженного магазина с количеством товаров 300к+ только **Magento**, только со **2й** версии, только **ЕЕ**. На данный момент более достойного e-commerce инструментария для больших решений не вижу.

З.Ы. 10 лямов товаров это круто. Есть такой ещё oscommerce, но с ним не работал, погуглите ;)